# How to convert array of arrays into array of objects in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```
$scope.students=[];

$scope.students[[object Object][object Object]]
               [0]{"id":"101","name":"one","marks":"67"}
               [1]{"id":"102","name":"two","marks":"89"}
```

i want to convert into following format like.

```
$scope.students=[{"id":"101","name":"one","marks":"67"},{"id":"102","name":"two","marks":"89"}]
```

i tried using .map function but not working,now i want to convert array of arrays into array of objects format by using angularjs.

Comment: The parts where you said "This is my code"... the following code isn't valid JavaScript. So... can you show us your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

If `students` variable is a two dimensional array such as below:

`students = [[{"id":"101","name":"one","marks":"67"}, {"id":"102","name":"two","marks":"89"}]]`

You can do double loop to loop through each array of objects, then push each object into an array you want to save it into. Below is vanilla JavaScript, but I am sure there are different ways to do it.

```
var students = [];
var results = [];

students = [[{"id":"101","name":"one","marks":"67"}, {"id":"102","name":"two","marks":"89"}]]

console.log(students); //array of array
console.log('-----'); 
console.log(students[0]); //array of object
console.log('-----'); 
for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) { 
    console.log(students[i]); //the array of object

  for(var j=0; j < students[i].length; j++){
    results.push(students[i][j]);  
  }
}
console.log('--Results---');
console.log(results);
```

Also check my JSBin: https://jsbin.com/tareku/edit?html,js,console